# Is there a simple way to batch rename symlink targets?

Tags: linux, shell

Something like [rename](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rename.htm) does for files but for symlink targets.

So if I have

```
link1 -> /usr/share/lib-1.2.2/file1
link2 -> /usr/share/lib-1.2.2/file2
```

I could do

```
rename 1.2.2 2.0.3 link*
```

and have

```
link1 -> /usr/share/lib-2.0.3/file1
link2 -> /usr/share/lib-2.0.3/file2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[util-linux-2.23](https://kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/v2.23-ReleaseNotes)

> ```
> rename(1):
>   - supports new command line option --symlink to rename symlink target
> ```

Comment: hi I am on ubuntu 17.04 and rename does not show an option for --symlink, is there another way of doing this:
:~$ rename -h
Usage:
    rename [ -h|-m|-V ] [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] [ -e|-E perlexpr]*|perlexpr
    [ files ]

Options:
    -v, -verbose
            Verbose: print names of files successfully renamed.
...

    -E      Statement: code to act on files name, as -e but terminated by
            ';'.

Comment: rename on debian is some perl script. rename from util-linux is installed as rename.ul. I assume it will be the same on ubunutu.

Answer (score 7):

Use this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
from="$1"
to="$2"
shift 2
for i
do
  a=$(readlink "$i") && ln -sf "$(echo $a | sed "s@$from@$to@")" "$i"
done
```

Usage example:

```
$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 1 -> /bin/1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 7 Jul 12 18:56 10 -> /bin/10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 2 -> /bin/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 3 -> /bin/3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 4 -> /bin/4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 5 -> /bin/5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 6 -> /bin/6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 7 -> /bin/7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 8 -> /bin/8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 6 Jul 12 18:56 9 -> /bin/9
<links>$ bash ../rename-links /bin/ /usr/bin/ *
<links>$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 1 -> /usr/bin/1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 11 Jul 12 18:57 10 -> /usr/bin/10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 2 -> /usr/bin/2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 3 -> /usr/bin/3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 4 -> /usr/bin/4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 5 -> /usr/bin/5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 6 -> /usr/bin/6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 7 -> /usr/bin/7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 8 -> /usr/bin/8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 igor igor 10 Jul 12 18:57 9 -> /usr/bin/9
```

Comment: That's exactly what i want to avoid but kudos on the shell-fu

Comment: I'm afraid, that is unavoidable :)